# UI - Customizing Slider Thumbh in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, slider, flutter-dependencies, seekbar

I am using Slider in Flutter for value selections but it needs to be customised as below :
[image]

Normally I can create default slider but how can I achieve this Thumbh UI on my slider? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following would do the trick. You have to customize the [SliderThemeData.thumbShape](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliderThemeData/thumbShape.html) and [SliderThemeData.trackShape](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliderThemeData/trackShape.html) properties to achieve that.

[image: Screenshot]

Here's a minimal reproducible example (Also, [live demo on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=15f831d6fd3eacc85cca23982e990f61))

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  double sliderValue = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            const Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0),
              child: Text(
                'Font Size',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 16,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Theme(
              data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
                sliderTheme: const SliderThemeData(
                  thumbShape: MySliderComponentShape(),
                  trackShape: SameHeightRoundedSliderTrackShape(),
                  trackHeight: 8,
                ),
              ),
              child: Slider(
                onChanged: (value) => setState(() => sliderValue = value),
                value: sliderValue,
                min: 0,
                max: 2,
                divisions: 2,
                activeColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 231, 231, 231),
                inactiveColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 231, 231, 231),
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: const [
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24),
                  child: Text('Small', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14)),
                ),
                Text('Medium', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14)),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 24),
                  child: Text('Large', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14)),
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MySliderComponentShape extends SliderComponentShape {
  const MySliderComponentShape();

  @override
  Size getPreferredSize(bool isEnabled, bool isDiscrete) {
    return const Size(34, 34);
  }

  @override
  void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset center,
      {required Animation<double> activationAnimation,
      required Animation<double> enableAnimation,
      required bool isDiscrete,
      required TextPainter labelPainter,
      required RenderBox parentBox,
      required SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
      required TextDirection textDirection,
      required double value,
      required double textScaleFactor,
      required Size sizeWithOverflow}) {
    final Canvas canvas = context.canvas;
    canvas.drawShadow(
        Path()
          ..addRRect(RRect.fromRectAndRadius(
            Rect.fromCenter(center: center, width: 38, height: 34),
            const Radius.circular(19),
          )),
        Colors.black,
        5,
        false);
    canvas.drawRRect(
      RRect.fromRectAndRadius(
        Rect.fromCenter(center: center, width: 34, height: 34),
        const Radius.circular(17),
      ),
      Paint()..color = const Color.fromARGB(255, 252, 241, 216),
    );
    canvas.drawRRect(
      RRect.fromRectAndRadius(
        Rect.fromCenter(center: center, width: 26, height: 26),
        const Radius.circular(13),
      ),
      Paint()..color = const Color.fromARGB(255, 235, 151, 72),
    );
  }
}

class SameHeightRoundedSliderTrackShape extends RoundedRectSliderTrackShape {
  const SameHeightRoundedSliderTrackShape();

  @override
  void paint(
    PaintingContext context,
    Offset offset, {
    required RenderBox parentBox,
    required SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
    required Animation<double> enableAnimation,
    required TextDirection textDirection,
    required Offset thumbCenter,
    bool isDiscrete = false,
    bool isEnabled = false,
    double additionalActiveTrackHeight = 0,
  }) {
    super.paint(
      context,
      offset,
      parentBox: parentBox,
      sliderTheme: sliderTheme,
      enableAnimation: enableAnimation,
      textDirection: textDirection,
      thumbCenter: thumbCenter,
      isDiscrete: isDiscrete,
      isEnabled: isEnabled,
      additionalActiveTrackHeight: additionalActiveTrackHeight,
    );
  }
}
```